# Seeking geographical database that, given coordinate boundaries, returns all the mountain peaks within the boundary, their coordinates, and elevation

Tags: data-request, api, geospatial, geocoding

I'm looking for a web service that, given a set of coordinate boundaries, in the form of a rectangle or square, returns all the mountain peaks within the boundary, along with the coordinates and the elevation of the peak.

Geonames offers such a service, but I have to make separate requests for the elevation for *each* peak, which could amount to hundreds of requests for a given (ie hilly) boundary.

Comment: Interesting question. If you are looking for a specific country or region (e.g. the US), can you update your question?

Comment: Global data would be ideal, but US data would be the next best option. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know any service, but it can be simply performed with GIS software using a free Digital Elevation Model - If you are interested, you can use [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) to tackle the process.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is another task for OSM.

- [Extract data within Polygon](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Select_Region_by_Polygon) or [by bounding box](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Bounding_box_clauses_.28.22bbox_query.22.2C_.22bounding_box_filter.22.29)
- Filter based on [tag Peak](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dpeak)

See some other questions about using OSM as a datasource, including the Overpass API, by searching here or Google

Answer (score 2):

[USGS GNIS Advanced search](https://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=138:1:0::NO:1:P1_SHOW_ADV,P1_SHOW_FIPS55:Y,) will allow you to choose a specific state and county and the attribute *Summit* and get the data for that area within the USA.